# How to calculate external pressure resistance of cylinders and spheres,

Tags: pressure, material-science, stress-strain

Although I have seen a lot of literature online about how internal pressure resistance is calculated (i.e the pressure in a gas tank) I haven't found anything about the opposite scenario (i.e the pressures on a deep sea submarine).

How would one calculate the thickness of material needed and stresses involved at high pressures externally? Please assume a very basic level of physics knowledge (I have GCSE knowledge for sure and can probably work out and search up some of the more basic stuff, but I'm certainly no engineer).

Comment: Interesting question, but it appears to be more about engineering than physics.

Comment: http://engineering.stackexchange.com may be a better match. Although it would be possible to simply move your question there, on various reasons it is better if you delete your question here, and repost there.

Comment: @heather: I would say, buckling, the main mode of failure of thin shells under external pressure, is a physical process.

Comment: The ASME Pressure Vessel Code would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

If the walls of the tank are thin enough, it fails under external pressure not because its material reaches the yield point, but because of instability (buckling). For example, a critical pressure for a thin-walled infinite cylinder of a perfect shape is $p=\frac{2 E}{1-\mu^2}(t/D)^3$, where $E$ is the modulus of elasticity, $\mu$ is the Poisson's ratio, $t$ is the wall thickness and $D$ is the diameter of the cylinder (http://cybra.lodz.pl/Content/6287/APM_56_20.pdf, APM-56-20, p. 819). You may wish to look at a video of buckling of a cylindrical tank under external (atmospheric) pressure https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0N17tEW_WEU.